Are commas required when saying 'separate but interlinked'?
In a sentence such as

This forms three separate but interlinked questions.

should there be commas round 'but interlinked'? Or no commas at all? I'm assuming a single comma after separate is incorrect.

This question is similar to: Usage of brackets/parentheses (etc). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Answer: << Nowadays, there is a move towards minimal punctuation, and zero offsetting punctuation around a parenthetical where confusion isn't introduced is a real option: 'I have decided that if it is sunny tomorrow I will go to the park.' This ...

flows more smoothly than
'I have decided that, if it is sunny tomorrow, I will go to the park.'
But either is acceptable.  >>

It's perfectly fine without commas.

Thanks very much - that was my instinct but I began to overthink it and lost confidence!
